# How to reuse of blade template that contains mysql fetched data in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, extends

I'm a beginner and i'm creating a view in Controller as below.

```
public function withdrawals()
 {
   return view('withdrawals')
     ->with(array(
     'title'=>'withdrawals',
     'withdrawals' => withdrawals::where('user', Auth::user()->id)->get(),
     'settings' => settings::where('id', '=', '1')->first(),
     'wmethods' => wdmethods::where('type', 'withdrawal')
     ->where('status','enabled')->orderby('name')->get(),
     ));
 }
```

So i'm returning view to `resources/views/withdrawals.blade.php`. There's another file `dashboard.blade.php` and creating view from `return view('dashboard')` for the dashboard. i want to reuse `withdrawals` view in `dashboard.blade.php` file as well without creating another one. How i can access this existing blade content of `withdrawals` *that's coming from database* in another blade template with all it's data?

Comment: does `dashboard` actually need to include the `withdrawals` view, or you just want the data that you currently are attaching to the view in your `withdrawals` method?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned that i want to get it's data as well from mysql. i tried. @extends('withdrawals') in dashboard.blade.php. it brings the whole page but without the data. i also want some specific part of withdrawals.blade page not the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to focus on Components & Slots in blade extension.

Check this out [Components in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

I basically use this while layout setup. As there are things like header, footer, sidebars which will be common in all pages. Please have a look, it might help you.

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('Admin::Layouts.head-scripts')
    @yield('head-content')
    @yield('page-style')
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

    {{------------------------------------------CONTENT GOES HERE-----------------------------------------}}
<div class="wrapper">
    @include('Admin::Layouts.header')
    @include('Admin::Layouts.sidebar')
    @yield('page-content')
    @include('Admin::Layouts.footer')
</div>



@include('Admin::Layouts.footer-scripts')
@yield('page-scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Use the @section and @overwrite syntax mentioned in the [other-blade-control-structures](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures) to achieve this.

```
@extends('default')

@section('content')

    {{-- First Panel --}}
    @section('heading')
        Welcome, {{ $user->name }}
    @overwrite
    @section('inner')
        <p>Welcome to the site.</p>
    @overwrite
    @include('panel')

    {{-- Second Panel --}}
    @section('heading')
        Your Friends
    @overwrite
    @section('inner')
        <ul>
        @foreach($user->friends as $friend)
            <li>{{ $friend->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @overwrite
    @include('panel')

@stop
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so how do i add all the data of `withdrawals.blade` inside `<div id="wd">` *to* `dashboard.blade` using above method? could you be more specific please?